# How to display the text/html returned by the api on the blazor page？

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-server-side

```
@page "/counter"

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@if (currentCount % 2 == 0)
{
    <iframe width="1660" height="1115" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/m8e-FF8MsqU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

}
else
{
    <iframe width="1660" height="1115" src="http://localhost:10726/api/Employee/HtmlReport" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
}


@code {
    int currentCount = 0;

    void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

Below is the returned text/html：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU7ec.png)

However, it cannot be displayed on the blazor page, but will be downloaded. How to do it：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qD8Wt.png)

I am using the code here：
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6U72bdyMahg&t=125s)

Thank you!

Comment: does the youtube link work fine?

Comment: Don't put relevant code in external links or pictures. The problem is in your API, not your client.

Comment: yes,youtube link work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Henk Holterman said, the problems is in your backend code. Here is a working demo:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET: api/<ValuesController>
    [HttpGet]    
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        string filePath = "test.pdf";  //test.pdf located in wwwroot folder
        var contentDisposition = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
        {
            FileName = "test.pdf",
            Inline = true
        };
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.ToString());
        return File(filePath, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
    }
}
```

Index.razor:

```
<iframe width="1660" height="1115" src="https://localhost:44304/api/values" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, it is ok to test your code, can you see where my api code goes wrong, thank you：[code link](https://github.com/pystudy123/BlazorReportDemo/blob/master/MyReport/Controllers/EmployeeController.cs)

Comment: Please share your api code first otherwise how can i solve your issue.

Comment: I know how to do it,it is ok，Just like your code。Thank you。